# pygame wont draw my circle in my pymunk simulation

Tags: python, pygame, pymunk

I'm fairly new to pymunk and I wanted to make physics engine for my future games, there's just a small problem, My code won't draw the circle that pygame is trying to visualize. Here's my code.

```
import pygame
import pymunk
import sys


def create_item(space):
    body = pymunk.Body(1, 100, body_type = pymunk.Body.DYNAMIC)
    body.position = (450, 50)
    shape = pymunk.Circle(body, 80)
    space.add(body, shape)
    return shape


def draw_items(items):
    for item in items:
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, item_color, item.body.position, 80)


def quit():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()


def display_update():
    screen.fill(bg_color)
    clock.tick(FPS)
    space.step(1/60)
    pygame.display.flip()


# Constructor
pygame.init()

# Constants and Variables
WIDTH = 900
HEIGHT = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
FPS = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Colors
bg_color = 30, 30, 40
item_color = 200, 200, 200

# Pymunk Variables
space = pymunk.Space()
space.gravity = (0, 500)
items = []
items.append(create_item(space))


# Loops
def main():
    running = True
    while running:
        quit()
        display_update()
        draw_items(items)


main()
```

I don't really know what the problem is here, it doesn't give me an error or something like that and I only get a clean blank canvas with my bg color.(also sorry for the bad comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to draw the objects before updating the display

```py
def main():
    running = True
    while running:
        quit()
        screen.fill(bg_color)
        draw_items(items)
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(FPS)
        space.step(1/60)
```

You are actually drawing on a [`Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) object. If you draw on the *Surface* associated to the PyGame display, this is not immediately visible in the display. The changes become visibel, when the display is updated with either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip).

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- handle the events by either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)
- limit frames per second to limit CPU usage